# Cannot run android project on netbeans : THIS TOOL IS DEPRECATED error

Tags: android, netbeans, deprecated

I've installed android for windows and want to develop on netbeans 6.8. I use nbandrdoid plugin, android platform 2.3.3 API 10 revision 1, android sdk tools revision 10, android sdk platform-tools revision 3. I've added the platform to netbeans and create a project, it's like everything is fine until I run the project and get this output at the console

```
init:
deps-jar:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\dummy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyAndroidApplication\build\classes
compile:
Updating zip: C:\Users\dummy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyAndroidApplication\dist\MyAndroidApplication.apk_

THIS TOOL IS DEPRECATED. See --help for more information.

Deleting: C:\Users\dummy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyAndroidApplication\dist\MyAndroidApplication.apk_
jar:
Result: -1
```

the emulator doesn't showed up at all. my first project code is like this
    package org.me.myandroidapplication;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 *
 * @author dummy
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here
    }
}
```

**What am I supposed to do?** thanks for your time.

**----- UPDATE -----**

I finally can fix this error. At first, I planned to install android SDK offline rather than using SDK Manager. So I followed up [this instruction](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html) and downloaded the components I need. Everything is extracted correctly except that when I extract the platform using IZArc the file kernel-qemu which located in */platform/images/* **is not extracted**. But when I manually choose the file from IZArc and drag it to any folder it's extracted. Therefore netbeans console output is like freezing because of that **emulator issue** and it not show any message that corresponds to that problem. Maybe this is about IZArc configuration but this error cost me for almost a week!

Answer (score 0):

I found [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) to work way better for android development than Netbeans, maybe give it a try?

Comment: I'd love too, but for now it's my task to make it runs on netbeans. thanks.

Comment: If this is for a company you work at, seriously tell them to use eclipse.

Comment: Fixed it for now.  It's like using anything but Visual Studio for .NET development... you might get it to work now, but you're asking for issues down the road with updates, feature releases, and doing more than the basic tasks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you fixed it?